# preventing browser from loading a file drop outside the drop tag

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-file-upload

I have implemented file drop using ng2 file upload .
The problem i am facing is that when the file is dropped outside the drop area browser opens it.
Is there any way to prevent this event ?
angular2/4

Answer (score 6):

yes finally got it working .I hope it will be helpful for developers.
just add this to the component tags.

```
    onDragStart="return false;" ondragenter="return 
    false;" ondragover="return false;" ondrop="return false;"
```

eg:

```
    <div class="row" onDragStart="return false;" ondragenter="return 
    false;" ondragover="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
```

Comment: nice post. I was also searching for this issue, thanks, but this code should be added to main div of the component html